# Sequential writing from different hosts to one SD/SDIO

Tags: embedded, sd, sdio

I was wondering if it is possible to access one SD card via two or more hosts via some sort of hub and write to it data sequentially (i.e host1 writes a bulk then hostN writes another bulk)

Comment: Sure. The card won't really care who's writing to it, as long as it gets the correct signals for writing. It doesn't know how your circuit works.

Answer (score 1):

You need a high speed demultiplexer designed for SD interfaces.

Take a look at this TI's transceiver:  TS3A27518E-Q1